# Update a property in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, immutability

I try to increment a quantity property in an array of objects with React.
But I can't figure out how I can reach the item to update.

What I tried:

```
const initialState = {
  items: [{
      id: 254,
      quantity: 1
    },
    {
      id: 493,
      quantity: 1
    }
  ],
};

const payload = {
  id: 254
};

function updateProduct(state, action) {
  return state.items.map((item, i) => {
    if (item.id === action.id) {
      return {
        ...state,
        items: [
          ...state.items,
          {
            [i]: {
              quantity: state.items[i].quantity + 1
            }
          }
        ]
      };
    }
  });
}
```

The returned object should be:

```
{
  items: [{
      id: 254,
      quantity: 2
    },
    {
      id: 493,
      quantity: 1
    }
  ],
}
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: What do you mean by "without mutating"? You have to mutate in order to have the connected components update

Comment: Are your id's unique?

Comment: @Robert Yes the ids are unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will suggest a few changes:

1. Use the convention of action with {type, payload}
2. Perform the action in a reducer.

so this yields:

```
const reducer = (state, action) => {
  const {type, payload} = action;

  switch(type) {
    case 'update_quantity':
      const {id: itemId, quantity} = payload
      return ({
        ...state,
        items: state.items.map(item => (item.id === itemId ? {...item, quantity} : item)
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

and then, to update:

`dispatch({type: 'update_quantity', payload: {id: 'xxx', quantity: 3}});`

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you digged a little deep there. Based on the data you provided, isnt this as simple as:

```
function updateProduct(state, action) {
  return state.items.map((item, i) => {
    if (item.id === action.id) {
       return {
         ...item,
         quantity: item + 1
       }
    } else {
       return item
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: It's much cleaner that way... But it only updates the item object, not the state.

Comment: @SLePort did Meir's answer below not work? I thought that would be enough to update state.

Answer (score 0):

first of all you have to clone/store your arr state/values in new variable

```
let state = [...initialState.items] // now you have all the values in state var

// and then mutate the state
let mutatedState = state.map(el => {
  //modify data how you need
});

// Then assign mutatedState to initialState.items

initialState.items = mutatedState 
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want

```
{
  items: [{
      id: 254,
      quantity: 2
    },
    {
      id: 493,
      quantity: 2 // <<<<<<<<<<<< 2 here as well
    }
  ],
}
```

and also assuming you can use the latest and greatest of ECMA Script:

```js
const initialState = {
  items: [{
      id: 254,
      quantity: 1
    },
    {
      id: 493,
      quantity: 1
    }
  ],
};

const reduceIncrementQuantity = (item) => ({...item, quantity: item.quantity + 1});
const reduceIncrementQuantities = (state) => ({items: state.items.map(reduceIncrementQuantity)});

console.log(reduceIncrementQuantities(initialState));
```

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION:**

To be simple, Deep clone the object (state) and increment the specified value.

```js
const initialState = {
  items: [{
      id: 254,
      quantity: 1
    },
    {
      id: 493,
      quantity: 1
    }
  ],
};
  
const payload = {
  id: 254
};
  
  
console.log (updateProduct(initialState, payload));

function updateProduct(state, action) {
  var newState = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state));
  var isFound = false;
  newState.items.forEach(item => {
    for (var prop in item) {
    if (prop === 'id' && item[prop] == action.id) {
      item.quantity++; isFound = true; break;
    }
    }
    if (isFound) return;
  });
  return newState;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write this as,

```
function updateProduct(state, action) {
  return { ...state, 
    items: state.items.map(item => ({ 
       ...item, 
       quantity: action.id === item.id ? item.quantity + 1 : item.quantity 
    })) 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is how I usually update items in redux store array**
You can do it like this:

```
function updateProduct(state, action) {

  let updatedItems = state.items.map((item)=>{

  if(item.id=== action.id){
      return {...item,quantity:item.quantity+1}
    }
    return item
  })
  return {...state, items:updatedItems}
}
```