# How to update a value of one property of an object in an array using this.setState?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, multidimensional-array, state

Trying to change the value of one object within an array when I perform an image upload.

Image is coming from a child component with an identifying name, then I loop through the array (stored in state) and try to replace the corresponding object's image prop. Also attempted with a forEach.

I've tried all of the solutions on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57071044/update-a-property-in-an-array-of-objects) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29537299/react-how-to-update-state-item1-in-state-using-setstate), but sadly getting no where.

Here are my two latest attempts:

```
handleImageUpload = (data) => {

// method 1
    for (let i = 0; i <= this.state.artists.length; i++) {
      console.log(data);
      if (this.state.artists[i].artist === data.artist) {
        let artists = [...this.state.artists];
        let newArtistEdit = {
          name: data.name,
          image: data.image,
        };
        artists[i] = newArtistEdit;
        this.setState({ artists });
      } else return;
    }


// method 2, using immutability helper
    for (let i = 0; i <= this.state.artists.length; i += 1) {
      try {
        if (this.state.artists[i].artist === data.artist) {
          this.setState((prevState) => ({
            artists: update(this.state.artists, {
              i: { image: { $set: data.image } },
            }),
          }));
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
      }
    }

};
```

Any ideas why the image prop for artist[i] is never getting updated?

For reference: method 1 doesn't update anything, and method 2 adds a new state property called 'null', containing the image.

Comment: Can you show us your `artists` state?

Comment: Doesn't each `artist` don't have an `id`? Can't you do `artists[i].artist.id === data.artist.id`?

Comment: in App.js it's literally just:

state = {
artists: [],
}

Then when it's updated by new input, it becomes:

artists: [
{artist: 'foo fighters', image: null}
{artist: 'the who', image: null}
]

I set image to null by default, and no there's no id for each but shouldn't be necessary as I'm matching artists on names.

Comment: And what's the value of `data` argument would look like?

Comment: This is from the child component:

`onImageUpload = (e) => {
    const artistInfo = {
      artist: this.props.match.params.artistName,
      image: e.target.value,
    };
    this.props.onImageUpload(artistInfo);
  };
`

The event is a file upload.

Comment: Hmmm maybe are you looking something like [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/summer-voice-onig8?file=/index.html)?

Comment: oh my god you legend, this worked.

But why does it work? As far as I can tell it's checking current artist name vs data's artist name - that's understandable.

But how does simply writing `return { ...currArtist, ...data }` end up replacing the image prop?

Comment: I'm merging the objects using `spread operator`. Whatever property on `currArtist` will be replaced by the property on `data`, given that they have the same name.